# Replacing values in certain columns based on a dictionary of thresholds?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get from this Panda df:

```
   mag  ip    em   as_ppm  au_ppm
0  820  6447  99    4670      30
1  774  5827  26      35      97
2  800  9089  75    9727      25
3  584  6122  38    2911      80
4  494  7616  78    6673      67
5  742  6626  30    9424      69
6  803  2136  71    4043      73
7  682  8172  43    8806      26
8  132  1369  41    8267      34
9  680  5536  41    4431      16
```

Using these thresholds:

```
lowThresholds = {'mag':500,'ip':5000, 'em':0, 'as_ppm':0, 'au_ppm':0}
highThresholds = {'mag':1000,'ip':7500, 'em':90, 'as_ppm':8000, 'au_ppm':90}
```

To a matrix with the same shape with trues and falses:

```
   mag   ip    em    as_ppm  au_ppm
0  True  True  False True    True 
1  True  True  True  True    False
2  True  False True  False   True 
3  True  True  True  True    True 
4  True  False True  True    True 
5  True  True  True  False   True 
6  True  False True  True    True 
7  True  False True  False   True 
8  False False True  False   True 
9  True  True  True  True    True
```

and ideally using:

```
weights = {'mag':5,'ip':10, 'em':5, 'as_ppm':20, 'au_ppm':30}
```

end up with:

```
   mag    ip  em  as_ppm  au_ppm
0  5      10  5   20      30
1  5      10  5   20      0
2  5      0   5   0       30
3  5      10  5   20      30
4  5      0   5   20      30
5  5      10  5   0       30
6  5      0   5   20      30
7  5      0   5   0       30
8  0      0   5   0       30
9  5      10  5   20      30
```

I have found some terrible ways of doing it by creating various new dataframes, but I know it will scale terribly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
s=(df.lt(highThresholds) & df.gt(lowThresholds)).mul(weights)
   mag  ip  em  as_ppm  au_ppm
0    5  10   0      20      30
1    5  10   5      20       0
2    5   0   5       0      30
3    5  10   5      20      30
4    0   0   5      20      30
5    5  10   5       0      30
6    5   0   5      20      30
7    5   0   5       0      30
8    0   0   5       0      30
9    5  10   5      20      30
```

Answer (score 2):

For mask chain [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) and
[`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and then use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and
[`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), but I think @YOBEN_S answer should better scaling:

```
m = df.gt(lowThresholds) & df.lt(highThresholds)

df = df.mask(m, pd.Series(weights), axis=1).where(m, 0)
print (df)
   mag  ip  em  as_ppm  au_ppm
0    5  10   0      20      30
1    5  10   5      20       0
2    5   0   5       0      30
3    5  10   5      20      30
4    0   0   5      20      30
5    5  10   5       0      30
6    5   0   5      20      30
7    5   0   5       0      30
8    0   0   5       0      30
9    5  10   5      20      30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in ['mag', 'ip', 'as_ppm', 'au_ppm', 'em']:
   df[key] = list(map(df[key].values, lambda x: x > lowThresholds[key] and x < highThresholds[key]
```